# how to refresh div without refreshing all php data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, refresh

I would think this is simple but cannot figure it out for the life of me.. I want to refresh a div without refreshing everything.. I have a timer on each image that counts down from 24 hrs to 0 then disappears.. it all works but I cant seem to just refresh the timer div..

My php -

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $path = $row['path'];
    $user = $row['user'];
    $update = $row['update_date'];

    $timeFirst  = strtotime($date);
    $timeSecond = strtotime($update);
    $timeSecond = $timeSecond + 86400;
    $timer = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;

if($timer <= 0){

}else{
    echo '<img id="pic" src="/v2/uploads/'.$path.'"/>';
    echo '<div id="user">#'.$user.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="timer">'.$timer.' </div>';

    }
  }
}
```

I would like to refresh just the timer at 1 second intervals not the images.. I know I can use ajax to call it from an external file that loads all the content also as far as I know..Still new at this. *side not this is chopped up code for the example not all of it.

Comment: Ajax does not refresh anything. You can use ajax to request data from server, and do with that data whatever you want. You need to make a php script which will return just $timer data and then you can replace old data easily with jQuery.

Comment: yes you are correct I meant load it with ajax, ok so it sounds like I need to maybe append it somehow? Im not good with that do you maybe have an example? Thank you @NikolaR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you could do something like this:

1. Add class "timer" to your #timer element (if you have more than one #timer element, use different ID for each element).
2. Create php script which returns new $timer whenever it's called:

**ajax-timer.php**

```
<?php

/* include file where $conn is defined */


$response = array();

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $update = $row['update_date'];

        $timeFirst  = strtotime($date);
        $timeSecond = strtotime($update);
        $timeSecond = $timeSecond + 86400;
        $timer = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;


        if($timer > 0) {
            //Add just timer to response array
            $response[] = $timer;
        }
    }
}

//Return json response and handle it later in ajax:
echo json_encode(array(
    'result'=>empty($response) ? 0 : 1,
    'data'=>$response));
die();
```

3. Request data from ajax-timer.php with $.ajax and populate data when response is received:

**timer-update.js**

```
var ajaxTimerThread = 0;
var ajaxTimerRunning = false;

function ajaxTimerRun() {
    //Prevent running function more than once at a time.
    if(ajaxTimerRunning)
        return;

    ajaxTimerRunning = true;
    $.post('ajax-timer.php', {}, function (response) {
        ajaxTimerRunning = false;
        try {
            //Try to parse JSON response
            response = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (response.result == 1) {
                //We got timer data in response.data.
                for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    var $timer = $('.timer').eq(i);
                    if($timer.length) {
                        $timer.html(response.data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //Request was successful, but there's no timer data found.
                //do nothing
            }
            //Run again
            ajaxTimerThread = setTimeout(ajaxTimerRun, 1000); //every second
        }
        catch (ex) {
            //Could not parse JSON? Something's wrong:
            console.log(ex);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start update on page load.
    ajaxTimerRun();
})
```

Comment: Ok so I made the changes and am getting this in the log - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…), it post all the data there is just no refresh.. Thanks again!

Comment: add `console.log(response)` in catch(ex) { } and see what you get as a response.

Comment: This is the output - <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in <b>/ajax-timer.php</b>

Comment: You must include file where `$conn` is defined.

Comment: Wow ya I am losing my mind.. I didnt have my conn file referenced through all my mayhem.. It works beautifully! Thank you again @NikolaR. you are awesome!

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!

Comment: So I am receiving this error after about 15-20 seconds and the page freezes - net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, any idea why? Thanks again @Nikola R.

Answer (score 0):

Toss your existing php code into a separate `.php` file

Then use a `jquery` method called `load()` to load that php file into your div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div_ID_you_want_to_load_into").load("your_php_file.php");
    var pollFrequency = function() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            return;
        }
        $("#div_ID_you_want_to_load_into").load('your_php_file.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    };
    setInterval(pollFrequency,18000); // microseconds, so this would be every 18 seconds
});
```

Now, within this code above is something is not needed, but can be helpful, and that is the `if (document.hidden) {return;}` which is basically a command to the browser that if the browser tab is not in-focus do not fire off the `setInterval` poll.

Also a good idea to keep in the `randval=` math stuff, just to make sure there is no caching.

Comment: Ok thank you! I see this will load the external data into a div in the current page but does it refresh all the data? I do not see where you are refreshing just the timer.

Comment: $.load tends to freeze browser until data is loaded. Async ajax request is better option.